# Spritely jQuery Plugin - Stop All Spritely Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-plugins, sprite

I'm developing a sort of 'booklet' with a set of pages that can be viewed one at a time. On each page, there is a lot of animation going on using the [jQuery Spritely](http://spritely.net/documentation/) plugin, both the pan() and sprite() methods, causing it to be very resource-intensive.

When the button is pressed to proceed to the next page, is there a concise way to stop ALL spritely animations that are going on? Or will I need to do so with each element manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a `scenes` object, with each of its child-objects having a boolean `active` attribute, a `create()` method, and a `destroy()` method (which toggled the `active` attribute).

When I clicked on a button that was supposed to display a new scene of animations, I first looped through the `scenes` object for any child-objects with their active variable set to true, and then I would call that object's destroy method before finally calling the create() method for the button that was originally clicked.